# Can a C++/CX interface inherit from IClosable?

Tags: windows-runtime, c++-cx

How does one declare a runtime interface that inherits from `Windows.Foundation.IClosable` in C++/CX?

Both of these attempts produce compiler errors:

```
public interface class MyInterface : Windows::Foundation::IClosable {
   /* bla bla */
};
==> error C2039: 'IClosable' : is not a member of 'Windows::Foundation'
```

and

```
public interface class MyInterface {
   /* bla bla */
   ~MyInterface();
};
==> error C2849: 'MyInterface' : an interface cannot have a destructor
```

Yet it cannot be that such inheritance is categorically forbidden in Windows Runtime, because some system-provided interfaces do inherit from `IClosable` -- for example, `IInputStream`.

I suppose I could define `MyInterface` in IDL instead and convert it into an external `.winmd` file with midlrt.exe before I compile the C++ code. That would be an unwelcome compilcation of my build process, though. Is there a way to specify this as C++/CX source?

Comment: `Windows::Foundation::IClosable` is mapped to `Platform::IDisposable`.  If a `ref class` has a public destructor, the compiler will automatically make that class implement this interface and map the `Close`/`Dispose` member to destruction.  What are you trying to achieve by forcing an implementer of `MyInterface` to also implement `IClosable`?

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: There's a name-changing mapping (to `System.IDisposable`) documented for .NET, but none for C++/CX. Anyhow, writing `Platform::IDisposable` instead just gives me yet another compiler error telling me to declare a destructor instead -- but as the second example shows, that doesn't work either. What I'm trying to achieve is to promise to a user of my code that the can call `Close()` on the `MyInterface` I'll be giving him, such that he can use whichever preexisting IClosable-based infrastructure for getting it called that he might already have available to him.

Comment: Okay, so this can't be done in C++/CX. Unfortunately my attempt at a workaround doesn't seem to work either: [Follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653250/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inherit from IClosable only if you do not use C++/CX.

The reason why you get the first error is because this interface is not a part of Windows.winmd metadata. This interface is declared in windows.foundation.h file ABI::Windows::Foundation namespace.

The second error appears because an interface cannot have a destructor.

MSDN: When you declare a public destructor, the compiler generates the code so that the ref class implements Platform::IDisposable and the destructor implements the Dispose method. Platform::IDisposable is the C++/CX projection of Windows::Foundation::IClosable. **Never explicitly implement these interfaces.**

Comment: The interface certainly is part of Windows.winmd. There's a declaration for it present in the dump of Windows.winmd that ildasm.exe produces.

Comment: Probably it is there, but hidden. It could not be found by the C++ compiler.