# How to declare interface that inherits from IClosable/IDisposable

Tags: windows-runtime, c++-cx

After being told in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14594171/can-a-c-cx-interface-inherit-from-iclosable) that my preferred solution was impossible, I'm now trying to implement a workaround. Instead of declaring my interface that inherits from IClosable in C++/CX, I'm declaring it in raw IDL. But that doesn't seem to work either.

I've created an IDL file `FooSpace.idl` containing

```
import "inspectable.idl";
import "Windows.Foundation.idl";
namespace FooSpace
{
    [uuid(01234567-89AB-CDEF-FEDC-BA9876543210)]
    [version(42)]
    interface Foo : IInspectable requires Windows.Foundation.IClosable
    {
    }
}
```

and generate Windows Runtime metadata from it with

```
midlrt /nomidl /metadata_dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral" FooSpace.idl
```

The generated `FooSpace.winmd` looks alright when I disassemble it with `ildasm` -- in particular, `Foo` appears to inherit from `IClosable` in just the same way `IInputStream` does in the system-provided `Windows.winmd`.

However, when I try to use it from C++/CX -- not even implement it, just pretending for the time being that someone else has implemented it with WRL or whatever -- it doesn't seem to work. Here's my test C++/CX source file:

```
void works(Windows::Storage::Streams::IInputStream^ istream) {
  Platform::IDisposable^ local = istream ;
}
void doesnt(FooSpace::Foo^ foo) {
  Platform::IDisposable^ local = foo ;
}
```

which produces an error for `Foo` but not for `IInputStream`:

```
C:\cygwin\tmp>cl /nologo /c /ZW /FU FooSpace.winmd  testit.cpp
testit.cpp
testit.cpp(5) : error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'FooSpace::Foo ^' to 'Platform::IDisposable ^'
        No user-defined-conversion operator available, or
        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

What am I doing wrong here?

---

On the other hand the equivalent C# code seems to compile fine:

```
public class Whatever {
  public static void Works(Windows.Storage.Streams.IInputStream istream) {
    System.IDisposable local = istream ;
  }
  public static void AlsoWorks(FooSpace.Foo foo) {
    System.IDisposable local = foo ;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a call to mdmerge to your cmds it should work:

```
midlrt /nomidl /metadata_dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral" FooSpace.idl
mdmerge -metadata_dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral" -i "." -o "merged" -v -partial
cl /nologo /c /ZW /FU merged\FooSpace.winmd /EHsc testit.cpp
```

With the 'merged' winmd file I am able to compile code like:

```
namespace ClosableTest
{
    ref class Test sealed
        : FooSpace::Foo
    {
    public: 
        virtual ~Test()
        {
           FooSpace::Foo^ f = nullptr;
           Platform::IDisposable^ d = f;
        }
    };
}
```

The original FooSpace.winmd file that is generated by midlrt references Windows.Foundation (C:\Windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.Foundation.winmd) while the mdmerge output references Windows (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Windows.winmd).

It is interesting that you were able to reference the mildrt-output winmd file in a c# project without problems because in the blog post [How to reference C++ WRL Components from a .NET project](http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2012/03/28/how-to-reference-c-wrl-components-from-a-net-project/) Kevin Stumpf describes that he had some problem when not using mdmerge first.